# Autolayout self-sizing cells and UITableView stuttering/jiggling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Learning efficient ways of calculating the height of dynamic tableview cells with autolayout. Faced the problem when scrolling table view, it begins to stutter a little bit, which is very annoying. Sometimes it stutters a lot when scrolling up, but that is probably related to my demo core data code.

[This](https://youtu.be/WSNSDPBVHk8) video demonstrates the problem. The sample project is on [github](https://github.com/Sega-Zero/VK-Sample-App) repository (see [SZNewsFeedViewController](https://github.com/Sega-Zero/VK-Sample-App/blob/master/VKSampleApp/SZNewsFeedViewController.m)).

The layout of the cell is very simple:
[image: layout screenshot]

My first guess was looking at blended layers in the simulator, but it's fine:
[image: color blended layers screenshot]

Stuttering does not go away if I comment out images setting, so, that is probably not the real reason. I set the images asynchronously with [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache). I think I could watch for active scrolling and skip images setting until it stops completely, but I'm not sure if this could really help.

Replacing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` code with `return 250` does not solve the issue completely too.

Right now I change the height constraint constant for posts with images, will try a separate cells for plain text posts and images posts.

Can you point me out, what may cause such a stuttering and what can i try more to solve it? What's wrong with my layout or height calculating code?
Is there any appropriate way to pre-calculate heights (with the same values as `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` returns) in the background thread and save it to core data model, to be able to reuse those values fast?

**EDIT**: the profiler say that height calculating takes most of the time:
[image: profiler screenshot]

**UPD**:
Ok, seems like a separate cells + height caching is a better solution - tableview jiggles less for a little bit. Also, `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` seems to be more harmful then helpful. Removing this method removes jiggling a little bit more too. I figured out that after the approaches above, `[collectionview reloadData]` call affects most of all - removing this call leads to almost no jiggling. I will try static imageviews + watching the active scrolling to determine if this wouldn't lead to jiggling.

Comment: Before assuming that the problem is with autolayout and not your code, you must run the time profiler to see what methods are taking the most time. You can then choose what to optimise based on real data.

Comment: Attached a screenshot of profiler. Nothing consumes more time than height calculating.

Comment: What is `[SZNewsFeedViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:isOffScreen:]` that signature is inside your row height method and the parameter "isOffScreen" sounds like you're processing stuff for every cell?

Comment: this method sets the labels text mostly. No hard calculations, as you may see in the [source code](https://github.com/Sega-Zero/VK-Sample-App/blob/master/VKSampleApp/SZNewsFeedViewController.m#L168) of the sample project

Comment: I'm struggling with these issues as well, what do you do instead of `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`? I have a problem where not setting that causes the table view to jump around when scrolling from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Well, you can keep it, it doesn't affect much on the total jiggling. You have to keep the cell's content as much static as possible. No collection views, no table views, their reloadData somehow affects scrolling. Also, try to prevent cells height to be more than screen height

Comment: @Steve, you'll probably find [this](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5) article interesting

Comment: @Sega-Zero is doing data stuff in willDisplay really better? Apple don't seem to suggest that anywhere and always set data in cellForRowAtIndexPath in docs / sample code.

Comment: That might be better. Of course, it depends on data. Simple text may be set at any time. Complex graphics, animation-driven content, video etc may and should be set in willdisplay. Also, the article above is a little wrong about slow autolayout - the author just can't cook it =) When you keep your layout simple enough - nothing bad will happen. Also, the tableview appears to stutter even in case of manual height calc, so you have to implement several techniques to achieve smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're still implementing heightForRow:atIndexPath: and not utilizing UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: 1. The project is ios7+, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is ios8+ only.
2. Tried that, didn't help actually